# joining tables on where the column name equals the value of a cell

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am not very sharp with sql, and I have a question.
I have two tables that when simplified looks like that:

**T1**

```
id |     name     | photo
1  | robert       | img1.jpg
2  | john         | img2.jpg
1  | jess         | img3.jpg
```

**T2**

```
id |     title    | field
1  | User Name    | name
2  | User Photo   | photo
```

I want the output to be like that:

```
     User Name    | User Photo
     robert       | img1.jpg
     john         | img2.jpg
```

In simple explanation I want to get the value of the title column from T2 where the field value equals to the column name on T1 and switch it with the output table column names.

Is it possible to do that?
How?

Thanks!
Ran

Comment: The output is just T1 with different column names. You can do this with an alias.

Comment: How do I get the value of the field column from the T2 table to be the alias of the output table?

Comment: Why would you want to? You already know it. Unless your example is oversimplified this is a complete non question

Comment: The second table is dynamic and contains data for lots of tables similar to T1. and contains a little more data than what T2 here shows. I simplified it only to the relevant part of the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821970/joining-tables-on-where-the-column-name-equals-the-value-of-a-cell?noredirect=1#comment40395404_25821970), your desired output is simply T1 with aliases.

Aliases can be used like:

```
SELECT `name` AS `User Name`, `photo` AS `User Photo`
FROM `T1`;
```

It's not possible to use dynamic aliases in any RDBMS that I know of and certainly not in MySQL. Doing something like:

```
SELECT  `name` AS ( SELECT `title`
                    FROM `T2`
                    WHERE `field` = 'name'),
        `photo` AS (SELECT `title`
                    FROM `test`.`title_photo`
                    WHERE `T2`)
FROM `T1`;
```

Will give a syntax error.

Even if it would let you do that, you don't gain anything from it as it's just a name for the column and it's a direct 1 to 1 translation - just hard code it directly as an alias.